# Go JSON Marshaller errors when converting int64 bytes

Tags: json, go, time, marshalling, int64

I am writing a time alias to JSON Marshal some time into a Unix format (left some of my experimenting test code in there

```
type NotifyTime time.Time

// MarshalJSON implements marshaller interface. Marshals time.Time into unix time in bytes
func (t NotifyTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // unixTime := time.Time(t).Unix()
    unixTime := 1626132059 // unixTime := time.Now().Unix()
    buffer := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.PutVarint(buffer, int64(unixTime))
    // binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(buffer, uint64(unixTime))

    // try to convert back
    fmt.Println(string(buffer))
    unixIntValue := int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(buffer))
    fmt.Println(unixIntValue)

    return buffer, nil
}
```

When I run json.Marshal on an object with NotifyTime struct, it errs, with the following,
json: error calling MarshalJSON for type notify.NotifyTime: invalid character '¶' looking for beginning of value

```
        type TestMe struct {
            Time NotifyTime `json:"time"`
        }
        testJSON := TestMe{
            Time: NotifyTime(time.Now()),
        }
        marshalled, err := json.Marshal(testJSON)
```

I have switched to marshalling it as a string, but still curious as to why this happens. When stepping through the code it seems to be because
on function compact on go/1.16.2/libexec/src/encoding/json/indent.go:17
it is looping over the marshalled bytes of the JSON
and the first (0th) byte fails the checks in
go/1.16.2/libexec/src/encoding/json/scanner.go:247

Comment: Your `MarshalJSON` returns something that's definitively not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put aside the aspect of encoding a `time.Time` and lets focus on how the `int64` is being turned into JSON.

`binary.PutVarint` uses an encoding that is appropriate for low level wire or file formats. For the constant 1626132059, this writes into buffer `[182 185 230 142 12 0 0 0]`. The first character is `182  PILCROW SIGN` in [UTF-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec). This is where '¶' comes from. You are getting an error like:

```
json: error calling MarshalJSON for type main.NotifyTime: invalid character '¶' looking for beginning of value
```

This is not the beginning of a valid JSON value. You will need to find an encoding of int64 that is a JSON value, such as a decimal number `1626132059` or a string of hexadecimal digits `"60ecce5b"`.

In general you need to be careful putting binary string values into JSON as these can contain special characters that need to be escaped.